# how to display a div with multiple conditions in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display a div according to some condition but it is not working properly.
i have some user like admin and visitor  and some more profile, and there is one more condition associated with admin let take that condition isBusy(boolean).

i want to display particular div only for admin and visitor. and for admin when isBusy is true
here is my code-

```
{(user.isAdmin() && this.props.isBusy) || user.isVisitor() &&
<div>
some more code
</div>
}
```

**i want to show this div when user is admin and isBusy = true or user is visitor.**
these conditions are not working properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does it show if you console.log(user.isAdmin(), this.props.isBusy, user.isVisitor())?

Comment: can you please explain the scenario.. like what are the other views and roles.

Comment: all are boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake in brackets, see example for details
[CodeSandbox example](http://codesandbox.io/s/happy-knuth-8fmw5?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

You Can add all conditions in one bracket and try it.

```
{((user.isAdmin() && this.props.isBusy) || user.isVisitor()) &&
<div>
some more code
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{(user.isAdmin() && this.props.isBusy) || user.isVisitor() && (
    <div>
        // code
    </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try and debug the values of each condition (e.g. `isAdmin()`, `isBusy` and `isVisitor()`) to see the values they give. The reason why it doesn't render the div you want is probably that either one of those conditions is not met. Therefore, debugging let's you find out what is going on in your code.

If the values are all correct then try the following with ternary operator:

```js
{(user.isAdmin() && this.props.isBusy) || user.isVisitor() ? (
 <div>
  // code
 </div>
) : null
}
```